# Angularfire login with Facebook not recieving extended permissions

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I had this working perfectly before upgrading to angularfire 0.9

**I want to request the user's email address from facebook**.  Facebook has already granted me permission to ask for this from my users.  I am using the code below to login with facebook.  It all works perfectly accept that it doesn't request the user's email.

FYI: I am using the Angularfire-seed codebase

```
loginWithFacebook: function() {
      return auth.$authWithOAuthPopup("facebook", function(error, authData) { /* Your Code */ }, {
        remember: "sessionOnly",
        scope: "email, user_likes"
      });
    },
```

thanks in advance!

---

**In response to Mike's answer below, i've noticed that the function does not run at all.  not sure what the issue is.**

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://<your-firebase>.firebaseio.com");
ref.$authWithOAuthPopup("facebook", function(error, authData) {

   //THIS CODE NEVER RUNS

   if (error) {
      console.log("Login Failed!", error);
   } else {
      console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
   }
});
```

Comment: There's not enough context here for anybody to guess why that code does not run. That would entirely depend on where it is located. See [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$authWithOAuthPopup takes options.

It is also best to execute it as per the documentation example:

```
$scope.authObj.$authWithOAuthPopup("facebook",{remember: "sessionOnly",scope: "email,user_friends"}).then(function(authData) {
    console.log("Logged in as:", authData.uid);
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.error("Authentication failed:", error);
});
```

Comment: Any idea how this is supposed to change for Firebase 3.x / Angularfire 2.x ? It seems the new `$signInWithPopup(provider)` does not take options [link](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/reference.md#signinwithpopupprovider).

Answer (score 1):

I just hit this exact same problem. The AngularFire `$authWithOAuthPopup` does not seem to run the code in the function or request the email auth from Facebook. My temporary fix is to use `authWithOAuthPopup` (i.e. without the "$") as it seems as if there is a problem with the AngularFire wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this, If this doesn't work make sure that all your firebase and angularfire are updated.

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://<your-firebase>.firebaseio.com");
ref.authWithOAuthPopup("facebook", function(error, authData) {
  if (error) {
    console.log("Login Failed!", error);
  } else {
    console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't see how this helps me get the user's email address from facebook.

Comment: You'll be able to console log authData which should have email in it.

Comment: thanks, but i have already tried this, i am not getting the email.  facebook is not sending it

Comment: Ive also updated the scripts to the very latest and still nothing. I see all the other data but not email

Comment: Did you make sure that on the facebook developer you are requesting their email address?

If you console log authdata there should be an object in there called facebook.

You can then grab the email by saying something like authData.facebook.email