# Angularfire facebook user_friends

Tags: angularjs, facebook, firebase, angularfire

Using facebook authentication with angularFire, I don't see "user_friends" in the Auth object that is returned.

ng-click="auth.$authWithOAuthPopup('facebook',{scope:'user_friends'})"

This works fine for grabbing the uid, and I see the facebook object which contains the "accessToken", "cachedUserProfile" etc., but no "user_friends".

Someone is have a similar issue here with the "email" object:

[Angularfire login with Facebook not recieving extended permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28173893/angularfire-login-with-facebook-not-recieving-extended-permissions)

Am I missing something or is this a bug?

Thanks for any help/guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out you can turn around and use that token to hit the facebook Graph API like so...

```
$http.get("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/me?fields=friends&access_token="+authData.facebook.accessToken)
```